# App Rejected on 5. 1.1 Legal: Privacy - Data Collection and Storage

Tags: ios

My app is a business prospective app and it cannot be work completely without a user account. I gave the user the options to sign up with Facebook google or create a new account with his own details like email password and mobile number . Apple rejected the app and here is what they said

We noticed that app requires users to register with personal information to access non account-based features. Apps cannot require user registration prior to allowing access to app content and features that are not associated specifically to the user.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think login / register via SSO would be a reason for rejection. It's about something else. You should contact Apple approval team for further help.

Comment: Do you have put the privacy policy URL that describes properly what you do with the private data like mobile number? Sometimes they reject for this reason.

Comment: We have no indication of what your app does or what features might or might not be specific to the user, so what kind of help are you hoping for?

Comment: The application is a utility that connects users to workers who can provide various handy services very quickly and easily, in the fastest way from any location fire up your apps , enter the type of service required  plumbing , tailoring , auto-mechanic etc. and find a handy man to get things done.

Comment: This once happened to me (same reason for rejection). I contacted Apple and they approved it. So try to ask them first it might be a misunderstanding on their part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you need to ask for access to permissions first before you allow the user to use the feature.

Go into the .infoplist and add your permissions example :
Storge would need a storage permission 
Camera needs a camera permission.

Just google camera ios permission plist ect for each.

Comment: i am not using any camera feature in our app.

Comment: Data Collection and Storage.

You may be using storage or library to display a picture

Comment: Otherwise ask the apple approval team for more information

Comment: You may need to give a user demo account

Comment: yes i have asked from them. waiting for their response. and i have given one demo account.

Comment: @AkhileshKumar How did you fix it? please explain what steps you have performed to get it approved.

Comment: hello sir same problem for upload apps at time reject apps  like this issue find out  "please revise the permission modal alert to specify why the app is requesting access to the user's Camera and Photos."

Comment: @KingsleyMitchell sir  how to this problem solve any idea regarding my issues tell me sir....!

Comment: It is asking why have you got a camera and photos permission if you do not use camera and photos